# Destiny hero dark angels effect

Tags: yu-gi-oh

[Destiny Hero - Dark Angel](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Destiny_HERO_-_Dark_Angel) versus [Buster Blader the Dragon Destroyer Swordsman](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Buster_Blader,_the_Dragon_Destroyer_Swordsman)  plus [DNA Surgery](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/DNA_Surgery) on the field who's effect works? Or do they cancel each other out

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the situation? Please describe your scenario in more detail... did you use DNA surgery to make all monsters Dragons? What effect(s) do you ask if they cancel each other? What cards are on the field, is it your turn, etc so we can help you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can only activate the first effect, since while in your hand destiny hero - dark angel is no dragon. Since it becomes a dragon on the field, you can not activate it's effect due to the buster blader.

EDIT: Answering to your comment, if you mean DH Plasma, Then you are probably referring to its effect of negating opponents mosters effects. Since the Buster Blader negates only activated abilities, the continuous ability of Plasma is not negated. Then since Plasma negates Buster Blader, you could also activate it's second effect and equip him with the Buster Blader.

Comment: Sorry guys got it wrong I meant to say destiny hero plasma v buster blader with DNA surgery on the field